# Comma before where?

Tags: commas

Is a comma needed before the word "where" in the following sentence?

In 2015, I embarked on a paid position working at The Hospital of Sick Kids where I supported children with autism.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comma use before where and in which](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/383732/comma-use-before-where-and-in-which)

Comment: I would say you do need one, as the hospital is named and the rest of the sentence is  just additional information. If it was "...at the hospital where I was born", you wouldn't use a comma as the following words identify the hospital.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you Ms.Kate. Nice info for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar question was asked and answered on this platform
.
You can check with this link [Comma use before where and in which](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/383732/249803)